# Spacemacs: Run function after every file load

Tags: spacemacs

I have defined a function `fira-code` in `dotspacemacs/user-init` that runs the “setup” code for the Fira Code ligatures as described here: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Setting-up-Emacs

I then call this function in `dotspacemacs/user-config`. This *almost* works. When I first open a file, the ligatures are not shown, and Fira Code is not the current font. But if I then press `<space> f e R` to reload the config, it works. How can I make this work when first opening a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the function directly, add it as a prog-mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
  'fira-code)
```